# Using Neo4j Transactions with Python Bolt Driver

Tags: python, neo4j

I have some code that successfully creates a new node using the Python Bolt Neo4j driver.  However, I cannot create new relationships in the same transaction.

I am using Python 2.7 with the Neo4j Bolt drive 1.7.2.

```
    with conn.session() as session:
        uuid = getNewUUID()
        tx = None
        try:
            tx = session.begin_transaction()
            stmt = "CREATE (a:{type} {{{uuid_attrib}: $uuid, {name_attrib}: $name, {desc_attrib}: $desc, {has_phi_attrib}: $has_phi}}) RETURN a.{uuid_attrib}".format(                                                                                                                                                               
                    type=ENTITY_NODE_NAME, uuid_attrib=UUID_ATTRIBUTE, 
                    name_attrib=NAME_ATTRIBUTE, desc_attrib=DESCRIPTION_ATTRIBUTE,  
                    has_phi_attrib=HAS_PHI_ATTRIBUTE)
            #print "EXECUTING: " + stmt
            tx.run(stmt, uuid=uuid, name=name, desc=description, has_phi=hasPHI)
            create_relationship(tx, uuid, DERIVED_FROM_REL, parentUUID)
            create_relationship(tx, uuid, LAB_CREATED_AT_REL, labCreatedUUID)
            create_relationship(tx, uuid, CREATED_BY_REL, createdByUUID)
            tx.commit()
            return uuid
```

here is the create_relationship method:

```
def create_relationship(tx, startuuid, rel_label, enduuid):
    try:
        stmt = "MATCH (a),(b) WHERE a.uuid = '$startuuid' AND b.uuid = '$enduuid' CREATE (a)-[r:{rel_label}]->(b) RETURN type(r)".format(                                                                                                                                                               
                    rel_label=rel_label)
        temp_stmt = stmt
        temp_stmt = temp_stmt.replace("$startuuid", startuuid)
        temp_stmt = temp_stmt.replace("$enduuid", enduuid)
        print "EXECUTING: " + temp_stmt
        result = tx.run(stmt,startuuid=startuuid, enduuid=enduuid)
```

The code successfully creates the node in Neo4j.  However, the relationships are never created.  I expected the relationships to be added to the node.  If I copy and paste the relationship CREATE commands into the bolt web interface, the CREATE command works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the exact issue but it looks like transaction `tx` is passed as value and `create_relationship` function creates its own local copy of `tx` so original `tx` is not modified by the function `create_relationship`.

When you commit the `tx`, transactions from `create_relationship` function are not committed as these are not part of the `tx`.

You should consider running these transactions in the calling function itself instead of `create_relationship`, use `create_relationship` or similar function to create and return the statement and run these statement in the calling function.

**Function to get statement:**

```
def get_relationship_statement(startuuid, rel_label, enduuid):
        stmt = "MATCH (a),(b) WHERE a.uuid = '$startuuid' AND b.uuid = '$enduuid' CREATE (a)-[r:{rel_label}]->(b) RETURN type(r)".format(                                                                                                                                                               
                    rel_label=rel_label)
        temp_stmt = stmt
        temp_stmt = temp_stmt.replace("$startuuid", startuuid)
        temp_stmt = temp_stmt.replace("$enduuid", enduuid)
        print "Statement: " + temp_stmt
        return stmt
```

Replace

`create_relationship(tx, uuid, DERIVED_FROM_REL, parentUUID)`

with

```
tx.run(get_relationship_statement(uuid, DERIVED_FROM_REL, parentUUID),startuuid=uuid, enduuid=parentUUID)
```

Comment: Thanks Raj.  You are right.  The pass by value of the tx variable was the problem.  I changed the create_relationship method to return a string containing the Cypher statement and it worked.  Thanks again